# Laravel query builder use Mutator value in select

Tags: laravel, eloquent

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to:

- Join two tables (Invoices Table and Sold Products Table)
- Sum UNIQUE products `sold_products.quantity * sold_products.sold_price`

## What I have done:

```
ExportInvoice::rightJoin('sold_products', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id', '=', 'export_invoices.id')
    ->select(
        'sold_products.product_id',
        DB::raw('sum(sold_price * quantity) as bam') // I want to use the mutator not sold_price
    )
    ->groupBy('sold_products.product_id')
    ->get();
```

And everything works fine and return expected value.

## Problem is:

I have a mutator in `SoldProducts.php model` this mutator append to field `item_net_price`.
I want to use `item_net_price` instead of `sold_price` (AS I ADDED IN THE COMMENT IN THE CODE ABOVE).

Comment: The mutator comes from Eloquent, but a join creates a database builder. Thereby you lose the mutator.

Comment: So can you help me with a solution?

Comment: So what is your mutator?

Comment: Mutator `getItemNetPriceAttribute` just return `$this->sold_price * 1.14`

Comment: @AE1995 I have post my answer, you can try it.

Comment: make a raw query .i'll convert it into ORM or query builder form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `leftJoin` instead of `rightJoin`, so that you can use `SoldProduct` mutator.

```php
$product = SoldProduct::leftJoin('export_invoice', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id', '=', 'export_invoices.id')
           ->select(
        'sold_products.product_id',
// You cannot use mutator in DB::raw, but you can do it like this:
        DB::raw('sum(sold_price * 1.14 * quantity) as bam') 
           )
          ->groupBy('sold_products.product_id')
          ->get();
```

And then get mutator:

```php
$product[0]->item_net_price
```

Comment: Problem is that I want to use `item_net_price` mutator instead of `sold_price` in the `DB::raw()`

Comment: That is not possible

Comment: @MatthiasS you cannot use mutator in DB raw, but you can use `DB::raw('sum(sold_price * 1.14 * quantity) as bam')` instead of `SUM(item_net_price* quantity)`